# Mind play music while ghusl

Tags: practical-islam, islamic-philosophy, islamic-basis, ghusl, islamic-scholar

I'm deaf and my mind started to play music while I was doing ghusl and this is what I'm struggling with now. I'm worried if my ghuls is valid or invalid this always happens to me and it makes me worried sometimes. Please answer me in simple way also fast. I'm very impatient for a answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your mind is playing music it has no connection with your ghusl. If your body is properly washed,mouth and nose is rinsed properly your ghusl is valid.
Jazakallah Khairan

Comment: What do you mean by the first sentence?

Comment: Imagining the music in mind